# cygwin : cannot access to network drive

Tags: cygwin

I have some issue using cygwin to access the network drive.  I have three VM(A,  B, C).

**Environment:**
VM A(11.11.11.1) is used as NAS and I also created a share folder inside VM A.  I Installed cygwin on window VM B(11.11.11.2) and map a network drive(the share folder) from VM A. I used another Linux VM C to SSH access to VM B successfully  but  I cant access the network drive even I use net use command.

> --------Error msg:-----------
>
> $ net use z: \\11.11.11.1\share password /user:admin System error 5
> has occurred.
>
> Access is denied.
> --------end of error msg---------------

- Q1) How do I solve the above access denied issue?
- Q2) How do I configure VM B such a way that I can ssh  to VM B to access network drive without specifiying the net use command

I tried to use mklink also not working

> lrwxrwxrwx  1 Administrators              NODE1+None
> 18 Aug 22 07:25  share -> //10.10.10.1/share lrwxrwxrwx  1
> Administrators              Domain Users                       18 Aug
> 22 08:02  share1 -> //10.10.10.1/share

I tried to access share or share1. I got permission denied

Comment: vm B is window 2012 R2

Comment: At the bash prompt run CMD.com and see if you can access the shared drive. if not, it's not a Cygwin problem. It's a problem in windows. Can you do a net use from the CMD prompt?

Comment: I tired before. can

Comment: Read `https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#mount-table`and the cygwin help for mount, e.g. `mount --help`. (ignore a couple of comments I have deleted if you saw them. I created them on my phone, and messed up the formatting and, worse, some of the info.) Note that cygwin understands UNC paths, so `ls //11.11.11.1/` should work, OOB.

Comment: Thank you.  We need to be able to see the network drive under /cygdrive/z otherwise our application cannot work at all

Comment: Maybe something like (in bash) `/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /c "c:/Windows/System32/net use z: \\\\11.11.11.1 ..."` (slashes work as shown) followed by `mount [options] z: /cygdrive/z` with appropriate options?

Comment: I tried.  Same  error

Comment: not working.  I tried another method also not working

Comment: 1)lrwxrwxrwx  1 Administrators              NODE1+None                         18 Aug 22 07:25  share -> //10.10.10.1/share                                                                                                                          
2)lrwxrwxrwx  1 Administrators              Domain Users                       18 Aug 22 08:02  share1 -> //10.10.10.1/share

Comment: Try posting your question on the Cygwin users mailing list.